# Is God a Legislator or Executive? Or both?

Tags: catholicism, creation

I can see two ways in which one can see natural (physical) laws (three, actually):

1. God creates his creation, and natural laws, then His creation autonomously acts according to those laws
2. God creates his creation, and natural laws, but He himself is the one--for lack of better words--pushing the stones around making it appear as if they follow that law
3. (Less prevalent or relevant option I would guess) Natural laws co-exist alongside God, and any creation would need to follow them

Did pre-Reformation theologians address this question? Has this perception changed since the reformation among Catholic theologians?

Comment: 3 seems to imply that God would not be God, because the natural law would not then be derived from Him and His Act of Creation. 1 sounds like deism.

Comment: @SupportiveDante Yeah that's what I thought so I suppose 3. is going to turn out not relevant for the question. I just decided to include it for completeness sake.

Comment: 2 would be more Cartesian. #1 is closest to Catholic understanding

Comment: Could you define what you mean by natural law, please.  Some would include principles like "reap what is sown" in this category along with gravity, for instance.

Comment: @MikeBorden I mean natural laws in the sense of physical laws, not anything related to morality.

Comment: Do you seek answers from Catholics only or is the tag there because "pre-reformation" is in view?

Comment: @MikeBorden I need to scope somehow and I thought scoping to catholics would be most likely to produce results. And I expect this view to change from 2 to 1 the further in time we get. So in my naive assumption that theologists of the past mused over many questions, I thought getting a historical perspective might be nice. If that scope is too narrow, it's fine for me to broaden it.

Comment: I should not answer under the current scope.  God knowing the end from the beginning without limitations prior to creation may allow us to see God pushing stones about in a sense by the very act of creation.

Comment: @MikeBorden, I don't think (1) is meant to imply that God *can't* push stones if He wants. Obviously, miracles still exist in (1) as instances where God "takes control", and may extend to causing events which are improbable but not *overtly* miraculous. My understanding is that (2) requires that *nothing* happens outside God's explicit action.

Comment: @Matthew That is correct.

Comment: @Matthew For instance, if God knew (prior to creating) what the "location" of each electron would be at each instant of time across all of time and then He created He would be, in effect, causing that "location" to occur at that moment.  Doesn't this fall within your answer of "neither Option 1 nor Option 2, but something in between, and possibly beyond our comprehension"?

Answer (score 2):

First off, let me state that I'm answering in the assumption that "natural laws" means "laws of nature" (i.e. laws of science), i.e. *not* any sort of inherent *moral* laws. In other words, gravity, inertia, thermodynamics, and so forth.

I don't know of any pre-Reformation sources attempting to address this question. I'm not sure their understanding of science would have been sufficient to even know to *ask* such questions... so I'm just going to take a crack at what *I* think. Note that this is my own take, which may or may not be correct, but I'll give my reasons to help you think about this yourself.

Let's start with...

##### Option 3:

> Natural laws co-exist alongside God, and any creation would need to follow them

What does the Bible say?

| Hebrews 1:3 |
| --- |
| [Christ] upholds all things by the word of His power. |

| Colossians 1:17 |
| --- |
| [Christ] is before all things, and in Him all things hold together. |

| Psalm 135:6-7 |
| --- |
| Whatever the Lord pleases, He does, [...] He causes the vapors to ascend from the ends of the earth; Who makes lightnings for the rain, Who brings forth the wind from His treasuries. |

The Bible teaches that God is omnipotent. Certainly we know that God is not *bound* by natural law. But if God is not the source of natural law, what is? The above verses would seem to imply that God indeed *is* the source of natural law, and the [fine tuning of said laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-tuned_universe) would seem to further indicate that they aren't an "accident".

[One article](https://www.pccob.org/2020/04/30/god-sustains-all-things/) goes so far as to state:

> "[...] The steady will of Christ constitutes the law of the universe and makes it a cosmos instead of chaos, just as His will brought it into being in the beginning." (Theologian A.H. Strong)
>
> All things are indebted for their existence to the continuous sustaining action of God exercised through his Son. Nothing exists of its own inherent power of being. Nothing in all creation stands or acts independently of the Lords will. The so-called laws of nature are nothing more than the physical expression of the steady will of Christ.

Thus, as we probably expected, it would seem that Option 3 is Not A Winner.

##### Options 1 and 2

> 1. God creates his creation, and natural laws, then His creation autonomously acts according to those laws.
> 2. God creates his creation, and natural laws, but He himself is the one — for lack of better words — pushing the stones around making it appear as if they follow that law.

Interestingly, our arguments *against* Option 3 seem to make a strong case *for* Option 2! But is that really the case? The God of Option 2 might as well be [Randal Munroe](https://xkcd.com/505/); indeed, such a God might well be indistinguishable from an entity manually running a simulation.

Leaving aside the question of whether such a God is shuffling all the bits personally, or employing some sort of assistance, there are issues with this approach.

First, because it represents Creation in terms we can comprehend, it begs the question "where did God come from?". It also clashes with the idea that God is *omniscient*, knowing past, present, *and future*. The Bible repeatedly teaches that God [is not bound by time](https://www.gotquestions.org/God-time.html) as we are. This works when one understands that *time itself* is Created, and does not act on God the way it does on us. (Another problem with the Simulation Hypothesis is that it doesn't directly account for Free Will. Humans will *cannot* be the result of strictly material processes, or Free Will can't exist. Thus, humans *must* have some level of spiritual existence that is not wholly bound by the laws of nature.)

However, even if we've established that God exists outside of time, we've still shown that He *is* pushing all the bits around... right?

Well, hold on:

| Psalm 33:6,9 |
| --- |
| By the word of the Lᴏʀᴅ the heavens were made, [...] [God] spoke, and it came to be; He commanded, and it stood firm. |

| Genesis 1:3 |
| --- |
| God said, "Let there be light," and there was light. |

| Genesis 2:2 |
| --- |
| [O]n the seventh day God finished his work that He had done, and He rested on the seventh day from all His work that He had done. |

The image of God's Word having power is present throughout the Bible. He speaks, and it is accomplished. The picture we are given is not one of a micromanager, but one of a God whose power accomplishes His Will as easily as we might move an arm or a leg. We don't stop to think about our heart beating to pump oxygen-rich blood into the cells. We don't think about the complex mechanisms by which our cells turn food and air into energy, ultimately causing muscle fibers to contract. We just... move.

In the same way, *my* belief is that God isn't consciously directing every single atom. I believe He *can* do so, and I believe Creation would immediately cease to exist (or at least go catastrophically awry) if not for God's continued Power sustaining it, but I also believe the image of God having to actively and consciously "push all the bits around" Himself isn't accurate.

In other words, I would argue that the answer is *neither* Option 1 nor Option 2, but something in between, and possibly beyond our comprehension.

Comment: Clarification! Just what was needed, and so clearly put that even I can follow the line of reasoning. But, just to remove all doubt: your answer to the main question "Is God a Legislator, or Executor, or both?" is, it's "something in between" 1 & 2. You do say 'Neither', but does 'Both', or a bit of both, have a chance of consideration?

Comment: @Anne, "neither" and "both" are the same in this case. I'm using "neither" in the sense that (I believe) neither (1) nor (2) is *exclusively* correct.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have said seems to be a human looking at the matter from a human point of view. Scripture references, or any sources given to show where you got the ideas from, would be helpful. But if this is just your opinion, the danger of just getting opinionated answers arises. As a minimum, it would be necessary to define "natural laws" so that we are all on the same page. It may seem obvious to most people what "natural laws" are, but there was once a political party in Britain that used that phrase and boasted that some of their members could levitate from a crossed-legged sitting position, purely through meditation.

To answer your main question, "Is God a Legislator, or Executive, or both?" the Bible certainly shows him stating his laws which apply to humanity. That makes him a Legislator. The Bible also shows him carrying out his stated punishments on those who keep violating his laws - e.g. bringing about a global flood to deal with an incredibly wicked generation of people. He is also shown in the Bible blessing (rewarding) his covenant people when they keep his laws. He also is seen executing punishments on his covenant people when they persist in breaking the covenant (and the blessings and warnings of the consequences were written down alongside the laws they agreed to keep). That makes him an Executor. **The answer to your main question then, is "He is both"**.

If, however, you refer to "the laws of physics" which humanity has only discovered comparatively recently, the entire material universe runs according to those laws of the Creator. This seems to be what you are thinking of when you ask if God is *"pushing the stones around making it appear as if they follow that law".*

Really, I can make no sense out of that question. If you refer to illusions in the material universe, then that question needs to go into an appropriate section, which isn't 'Christianity'.

You asked if *"pre-Reformation theologians address this question".* ***Did they even ask that question?*** If you can quote somewhere that suggests they did, more could be said.

Comment: I think the OP is asking "is gravity a real phenomena (1), or is God constantly pushing on things (2) in a way that's *consistent* with the Law of Gravity?". IOW, "law" here is being used in the scientific sense, i.e. laws of physics.

Comment: The question is tagged Catholicism and this answer notably does not include any reference to that denomination's views. "Did they even ask that question?" Certainly, the questions around how does nature and motion work occur quite often in pre-Reformation intellectual thought

Comment: @Matthew  How astonishing that a Q about gravity (in pre-Reformation religious thought) does not mention either 'gravity' nor the fact that this invisible, universal force was not discovered until around the era of Newton, cusp of the 18th century). He discovered the law of gravity. Maybe that's why the OP does not mention that critically important word. Your comments appreciated.

Comment: @ eques  Point appreciated; I could hardly quote any Catholic views on the philosophical ideas about nature and motion working, when no refence to that was given by the OP! It’s a bit frustrating when questions assume an almost esoteric knowledge of what’s being asked about. None of us are mind-readers. As this is about natural philosophy, really, the Q might best be placed there. I still cannot see how pre-Reformation  religious philosophy, that had no knowledge of Newton and Einstein, can be asked about here.

Comment: Gravity is just an example. If my understanding of the question is correct, I could also list nuclear forces, heat transfer... in a sense, the God of (2) is [Randal Munroe](https://xkcd.com/505/).

Comment: @Matthew  Wry smile at the link. But shudder at the realisation that some people actually think of God in such terms.

Comment: In fact, I don't think that conception works. I'm working on an answer in which I will explain why...

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Yes I indeed meant physical laws such as gravity. Morality was out of scope but I see that it was ambiguous. I guess the same could be asked about laws in the sense of morality, but that wasn't the intention.

Comment: @eques Isn't the "Catholicism" tag simply there because pre-reformation is in view?

Comment: @MikeBorden your point being? Were there a such thing as Protestant theologians before the Reformation? Theologians would be Catholic or Orthodox (Eastern or Oriental, etc)

Comment: @Anne the OP does ask about pre-Reformation theologians which should give some context to what type of answer is expected. Pre-reformation theology may not have known about Newton or Einstein, but neither did those scientists invent entirely their scientific disciplines. That is, those theologians did have a tradition which included a form of natural philosophy and thus some conception of how the universe works even if they didn't have specifics like a law of gravity or nuclear forces understood.